# Adding other mathematical expressions to aggregate function

Tags: sql

Im trying to combine both `aggregate function` with other mathematical functions, such as:

```
SELECT student.name, (exam.midterm1 + +exam.midterm2 + SUM(student.grade*class.extracredit) AS FINALSCORE
FROM student, class, exam
WHERE student.name = class.studentname
GROUP BY student.name;
```

^ it won't work. What is the correct way to combine the aggregate function with other mathematial functions in `sql` ?

**Student table**

```
NAME                           GRADE
------------------------- ----------
Jason                             44
Edward                            11
David                             95
Sean                              76
Jason                             88
David                             76
```

**Class table**

```
STUDENTNAME              EXTRACREDIT
------------------------- ----------
Jason                              4
Edward                             2
David                              1
Sean                               4
```

**Exam table**

```
STUDENTNAME                 MIDTERM1        MIDTERM2
------------------------- ----------      ----------
Jason                             76             87
Edward                            60             80
David                             97             75
Sean                              82             79
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the structures of all the relevant tables (student, class, and exam) to get a specific answer, but at first glance, it appears as if you're missing a condition linking the `exam` table by studentname to the `student` and `class` tables.

Comment: Depending on the structures of those tables, you will probably need to make use of subqueries to obtain your desired result set.

Comment: Which Database it is, Sql Server?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the aggregate sum only across the multiple grades in the student table, and add JOIN clauses to join the student, class, and exam tables, then use a simple expression to sum the four numerical values, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    s.name, 
    s.total_grade + class.extracredit + 
       exam.midterm1 + exam.midterm2 as finalscore
FROM
    (select name, sum(grade) as total_grade from student group by name) as s
    INNER JOIN class ON s.name = class.studentname
    INNER JOIN exam on exam.studentname = s.name;
```

A more general answer is that the results of aggregate functions can certainly be combined in expressions with other values, but depending on the situation those other values may also have to be the result of aggregate functions or it may be necessary to add more conditions to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: getting "SQL command not properly ended" on `from student group by name`, @rd_nielsen

Comment: @user7186947 . . . The query looks fine to me.

Comment: Well, there was no semicolon at the end of the code; I've added one now.  And I just realized that you were *multiplying* the extra credit value by the sum of the grades, which seems odd, but if that's what you want, just replace the first "+" with "*" in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table structure, You have to calculate the `sum` between `student` and `class` tables and join the result with `exam` table as below.

Give a try as below.

```
SELECT 
    sc.Name, 
    (sc.GradeAndExtraCredit + exam.midterm1 + exam.midterm2) as FinalScore
FROM
    (SELECT Name, SUM(grade * extracredit) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) as GradeAndExtraCredit FROM student s INNER JOIN class c ON s.Name = c.StudentName) as sc
    INNER JOIN exam on exam.StudentName = sc.Name
```